# Pandas substrings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How do I extract the 5th and 6th character from the string in a column by using loc or iloc and create a new column?

My data frame:

print (df):

```
index effective date
0     2019-12
2     2019-13
15    2019-10
20    2019-09
23    2018-26
```

The following works but it give me the copy of a slice message:

```
df['pp'] = df['effective date'].str[5:7]
```

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Expected result is this without the warning:

print (df):

```
index effective date  pp
0     2019-12         12
2     2019-13         13
15    2019-10         10
20    2019-09         09
23    2018-26         26
```

I've looked through the recommended documentation but can't find anything that really does the job.  Any help is appreciated.

-Dave

Comment: Try `df.loc[:, 'pp'] = df['effective date'].str[5:7]`

Comment: I am not getting any error when i run the code the way you have it

Comment: can't you just split the data by '-'?

Comment: @pissall, tried your suggestion and it gives me the error message twice.

Comment: @SH-SF I'm now wondering if it has to do with my version.  I'm running 3.6.5.  The error is being thrown in the ipython notebook.

Comment: @Dave Firstly, it's not an error. It's a warning which you can choose to ignore. Try `df.loc["pp"] = df['effective date'].apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[-1])`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need `str.split("-")`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"effective date": ["2019-12", "2019-13", "2019-10", "2019-09", "2018-26"]})
df['pp'] = df['effective date'].str.split("-").str[1]
print(df)
```

---

or

```
df['pp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['effective date'], format="%Y-%d").dt.day
```

**Output:**

```
  effective date  pp
0        2019-12  12
1        2019-13  13
2        2019-10  10
3        2019-09  09
4        2018-26  26
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using slice function?

```
df['pp'] = df['effective date'].str.slice(5,7)
```

Also, I tried your method and I didn't receive the warning.

Answer (score 0):

while using df['pp'] = df['effective date'].str[5:7], i'm not getting any warning may be your need to update your python versio.
using datetime package you can create new column as day

df['effective date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.effective date, format = '%Y-%d')
for i in ( df):

```
i['day']= i.effective date.dt.day
i['year']=i.effective date.dt.hour
```

df.head()

it should be lenghty process but while we preocessing date values it will gives accurate results

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get part of data after '-' better use split function

```
df['pp'] = df['effective date'].str.split('-').str[1]
```

For data before '-'

```
df['pp'] = df['effective date'].str.split('-').str[0]
```